# How to get count of childnodes in XML file using XQuery

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I want to get or return the number of item(`<recROw></recROw>`) in an xml file using the XQUERY. Is there an easy way to do that in XQuery?

Here is my sample XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<DailyRecord>
  <recROw>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <status>active</status>
  </recROw>
  <recROw>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>James Bond</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <status>active</status>
  </recROw>
<DailyRecord>
```

Any help and ideas would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: u mean number of `nodes` ?

Comment: Yes number of nodes in an item(<recROw></recROw>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
count(/DailyRecord/recROw)
```

Comment: Okay. Sorry I'm just a beginner about XQuery and Java. Thanks for downing!

Comment: upvoted the question, thank you for posting your question in a precise manner.